# Unexpected query result inside each executorservice thread

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, executorservice

I am pulling data in batches (chunkSize=1000) for that I have implemented executor Service. In the below loop I am calculating the firstResult and sending to executorService to fetch data and insert into mongodb

```
for(int i = 1; i <= numOfBatches; i++){
   int firstResult = (i -1) * chunkSize;
   explicitAudienceCreationExecutorService.fetchFromMartAndInsertIntoMongo(firstResult,chunkSize,query,promotion,
       filterKeywords,audienceFilterName,programId,counttoReturn.get(0).intValue());
 }
```

This is my runnable task which is giving unexpected result while executing query

> For ex: when I am executing the code without any loop and directly pass firstResult as 302000 it prints in log
>
> firstResult 302000 queryResultSize 1000

But when I do this in loop I saw this in logs. This happens for several values.

> firstResult 302000 queryResultSize 899

```
package com.loylty.campaign.com.loylty.campaign.service;


import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static com.loylty.campaign.com.loylty.campaign.config.MongoTenantTemplate.tenantTemplates;

@Service
public class ExplicitAudienceCreationExecutorService {

static int classCount = 0;

@Autowired
CampaignExecutorService campaignExecutorService;

@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Autowired
AudienceWithCriteria audienceWithCriteria;

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());


public void  fetchFromMartAndInsertIntoMongo(int fr, int cs, TypedQuery<Object[]> qr, Promotion promotion,
                                             FilterKeywords filterKeywords, String audienceFilterName, String programId, int queryrernCont) {

    final int firstResult = fr;
    final int chunkSize = cs;
    final TypedQuery<Object[]> query = qr;
    campaignExecutorService.dotask(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                mongoTemplate = tenantTemplates.get(programId);
                final List<Object[]> toReturn  = query.setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(chunkSize).getResultList();
                classCount++;
                System.out.println("classCount "+ classCount);
                logger.info("firstResult "+ firstResult + " queryResultSize " + toReturn.size() );
                if (toReturn != null || toReturn.size() > 0) {
                    List<TGAudience> tgAudienceList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Object[] tuple : toReturn) {
                        HashMap<String, Object> queryResponseTuple = new HashMap<>();
                        int index = 0;
                        for (RequiredKeys selectProperty : promotion.getRequiredKeys()) {
                            queryResponseTuple.put(filterKeywords.matcher(selectProperty.getKeyName()).iterator().next(), tuple[index++]);
                        }
                        if (null != promotion.getAggregation() && promotion.getAggregation().size() > 0) {
                            for (Aggregation aggregations : promotion.getAggregation()) {
                                queryResponseTuple.put(filterKeywords.matcher(aggregations.getAggregateOn()).iterator().next() + "_" + aggregations.getAggregateStrategy().name(), tuple[index++]);
                            }
                        }
                        TGAudience tgAudience1 = new TGAudience();
                        String stringToConvert = String.valueOf(queryResponseTuple.get("CUSTOMER_MOBILE"));
                        tgAudience1.setMobile(stringToConvert);
                        tgAudience1.setCustomerId(String.valueOf(queryResponseTuple.get("CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_ID")));
                        tgAudienceList.add(tgAudience1);
                    }
                    System.out.println("tgAudienceList "+ tgAudienceList.size());
                    mongoTemplate.insert(tgAudienceList, audienceFilterName);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    );
}

}
```

CampaignExecutorService

```
package com.loylty.campaign.com.loylty.campaign.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.concurrent.*;


@Service
public class CampaignExecutorService {

private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

public void dotask(Runnable  runnable){
    executorService.submit(runnable);
}
}
```

Comment: Which impeletion of `TypedQuery<Object[]> ` do you use?

Comment: @user27149 sorry but I didnt get you. If you are asking the import then I am using  import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

Comment: I mean, do you use Hibernate or some else ORM framework and create `TypedQuery<Object[]>` with EntityManager?

Comment: @user27149 creating with entity manager not using hibernate

Comment: TypedQuery<Object[]> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, Object[].class);

Comment: May be `entityManager` is not thread safe. I suggest create a entityManager and `TypedQuery` in per `run` method.

Comment: @user27149 But the query is same for all threads . only setFirstResult is different